# writing bits into a c++ file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, huffman-code

I'm working on Huffman coding and I have built the chars frequency table with a

```
std::map<char,int> frequencyTable;
```

Then I have built the Huffman tree and then i have built the codes table in this way:

```
std::map<char,std::vector<bool> > codes;
```

Now I would read the input file, character by character ,and encode them through the codes table but i don't know how write bits into a binary output file.
Any advice?

UPDATE:
Now i'm trying with these functions:

```
void Encoder::makeFile()
{
char c,ch;
unsigned char ch2;
while(inFile.get(c))
{
    ch=c;
    //send the Huffman string to output file bit by bit
    for(unsigned int i=0;i < codes[ch].size();++i)
    {
        if(codes[ch].at(i)==false){
            ch2=0;
        }else{
            ch2=1;
        }
        encode(ch2, outFile);
    }
}
ch2=2; // send EOF
encode(ch2, outFile);

inFile.close();
outFile.close();
}
```

and this:

```
void Encoder::encode(unsigned char i, std::ofstream & outFile)
{
int bit_pos=0; //0 to 7 (left to right) on the byte block
unsigned char c; //byte block to write

if(i<2) //if not EOF
{
    if(i==1)
        c |= (i<<(7-bit_pos)); //add a 1 to the byte
    else //i==0
        c=c & static_cast<unsigned char>(255-(1<<(7-bit_pos))); //add a 0
    ++bit_pos;
    bit_pos%=8;
    if(bit_pos==0)
    {
        outFile.put(c);
        c='\0';
    }
}
else
{
    outFile.put(c);
}
}
```

but ,I don't know why ,it doesn't work, the loop is never executed and the encode function is never used, why?

Comment: As there are only 256 possible char values, consider creating an array of 256 instead of a map with char as the key. This may use additional memory if only a few possible chars are used, but will be much faster than map look up.

Comment: This is a project for school and my main goal is to make the program work, because, unfortunately, I have little time left

Answer (score 5):

You can't write a single bit directly to a file. The I/O unit of reading/writing is a byte (8-bits). So you need to pack your bools into chunks of 8 bits and then write the bytes. See [Writing files in bit form to a file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856514/writing-files-in-bit-form-to-a-file-in-c?rq=1) or [How to write single bits to a file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589460/how-to-write-single-bits-to-a-file-in-c) for example.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ Standard streams support an access of the smallest unit the underlying CPU supports. That's a byte.

There are implementation of a bit stream class in C++ like the 
[Stanford Bitstream Class](http://stanford.edu/~stepp/cppdoc/).

Another approach could use the [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) class.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier with a `std::vector<bool>` instead?

Comment: A C++ `bool` is not a bit.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès that's interesting. how's it implemented or any reference?

Comment: Need to have a look into the standard, but it is commonly a `int`.

Comment: 3.9.1/7 Types bool, char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types. A synonym for integral type is integer type.

Comment: std::bitset - The class emulates an array of bool elements